# ring with prescribed K group

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, ra.rings-and-algebras

One can construct topological spaces with prescribed homotopy groups or, say, homology groups. 
But is it possible to construct a ring with any given $K_0$ group? What about $K_1$ group et.c.?

I know very little about K-theory, so this question might be silly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every abelian group $G$ is the class group of some Dedekind domain $R$ (theorem of Luther Claborn), so we have $K_0^{red}(R)= G$.

Comment: Very nice! What about getting prescribed non-reduced $K$-theory via non-commutative rings?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you know any similar results about $K_1$?